# su as different user in Linux reports 'missing }'

Tags: linux

When I try to su as a particular user, it says 'Missing }.'

```
[root@host5 ~]# su user1
Missing }.
[user1@host5 /root]$
```

Which config file should I check to fix this?

Comment: Maybe the `.profile` or `.bashrc` for this user has some error in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was missing } in .i18n file. /etc/profile.d/lang.csh will try to read .i18n file if its present in user's home directory while su`ing.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably some syntactic mistake in the shell startup script of the user like, `.bashrc`

using the `source configfilename` command should help to pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unlikely, but I don't know the nature of your system and how much of a target it may be, but if all else fails I would download linux coreutils and replace the su command with that.

You can look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).